# Azure Application SQL Database slow spin up time

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I've got a little bit problematic task at work, maybe someone will be able to help.

We've got **two identical** applications running on Azure AppService. Both using Standard (S1) AppService, both using S2 Azure SQL Databases.

They're really identical, two apps running for different clients, doing the same things, using identical db-schema, which we have checked two times, manually and automatically via Visual Studio 2017 schema comparer.

Problem appears when we try to run app2 using db2. App1 with db1 works fine, App2 with db1 also works fine. App1 with db2 needs 10 seconds to handle ANY request, same for App2 with db2.

But... Both db's have the same schema, are hosted on (basically) the same logical Azure server, sharing exactly the same configuration. Even if it was for performance issues - db2 has less data in it, so should be even faster (single table diff of 746k vs 1.6k records)

We have exhausted basically every option available, we tried:

- Recreating and redeploying the app on different AppServices and AppService sizes, with the same result
- Recreating and redeploying SQL Database to new/another SQL Server inside Azure, even with upgrade from S2 to P2 performance
- Running app locally with debugger on to see what's going on - the same result ~10.1s of spin up time for every request.

I couldn't find anything responsible for it, either in Azure infrastructure or Application itself (app1/db1 pair works fine).

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please upgrade the tier to Basic and then go back to Standard, just to clear cache. Do your test of performance, then run the following query on Db2 with App2. What waits appear on the database? SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_wait_stats ORDER BY wait_time_ms desc. What are top waits?

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo that's what's inside after doing what you said.

https://imgur.com/LfTS4xG

Comment: Please do more testing and run the query again. I would love to see the difference between in terms of waits between the server-app with good performance and the server-app sluggish. With the same battery of tests.

Comment: Try to run the same query on both databases and check the two execution plans. Check the "actual" execution plans and not the "estimated".

Comment: Can you paste output of below query in your question ,add group by with timestamp to below query and paste output

Comment: `SELECT  
    AVG(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Average CPU use in percent',
    MAX(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Maximum CPU use in percent',
    AVG(avg_data_io_percent) AS 'Average data I/O in percent',
    MAX(avg_data_io_percent) AS 'Maximum data I/O in percent',
    AVG(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Average log write use in percent',
    MAX(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Maximum log write use in percent',
    AVG(avg_memory_usage_percent) AS 'Average memory use in percent',
    MAX(avg_memory_usage_percent) AS 'Maximum memory use in percent'
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats;`